# Choose between two multimeters

Tags: multimeter

I want to buy one low budget multimeter for regular use. I don't need any high end functions only the basic ones (measure current, voltage and resistance).

I have found these two multimeters [(1)](http://www.all-sun.com/EN/d.aspx?pht=911), [(2)](http://www.p-mastech.com/product/detail/324) in local stores. The first one costs 20 euros and the second one 16.5 euros.

As I want it for electronics projects the specs of both, regarding AC, DC current and voltage measurement, are more than enough for me. The only difference that I see as important is that the first one (the one from Allsun) can measure up to 20MΩ resistance when the second one can measure only up to 2MΩ (if you can see something else in the specs that I should notice feel free to point it out).

My concerns are which one has better build quality, which one is more reliable and which one's manufacturer is more reputable.

Something that I found odd is that while searching online stores, including Ebay and Amazon, I saw that the one from Mastech is very popular and is sold by countless sellers but the one from Allsun is hardly found. Does this mean something about the quality?

All in all which one would you recommend me?

Comment: I call bullshit on the 20M\$\Omega\$ resistance range.

Comment: Neither. They're obviously too embarrassed about their accuracy to specify it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If you felt compelled to pick one? :P

Comment: When choosing a cheap meter, choose the cheaper one. It's not like either one is all that, and you'll have 3.5 more euros... (note: I have good meters and cheap meters - each have a role to play; if or when you want a good meter, that's a different decision.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal those are my thoughts exactly! As I have said my only concern is whether I may need to measure any resistance more than 2MΩ so maybe the first one is more suitable...

Comment: As implied by @MattYoung it's unlikely to be accurate at 20 Meg anyway. Honestly, that's a place (measuring above 2 Meg) you'll hardly ever go. Going above a 1 meg resistor is frankly uncommon for most hobby electronics - that part of a used resistor assortment will be practically untouched in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it's an answer, really:

When choosing a cheap meter, choose the cheaper one. It's not like either one is all that, and you'll have 3.5 more euros... (note: I have good meters and cheap meters - each have a role to play; if or when you want a good meter, that's a different decision.) Some places you don't want to use your good meter (well, I don't want to use MINE anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

From the data that are available from the links mentioned, choose the cheapest multimeter.

Neither sellers published relevant data on the accuracy of instruments, or refers to special features.
I think that in this case, the difference in price has nothing to do with a difference in quality. Therefore, I think not buy the most expensive give some advantage, so I'd pick the cheapest.
If you're starting, it is sufficient precision.

Maybe later you want access to more accurate measurements, or other characteristics, in which case you should ALWAYS consult the instrument manual before purchase.